# Spotfire Real-Time Calculations

Tags: spotfire

Trying to see if there's a good way to overcome real-time data sets, where there are differences in time. An example of my data looks like this:

Date-Time Stamp                     Depth              Total Time Worked (Hrs)

01/01/2023 12:00am              1000                       0

01/01/2023 12:01am              1009                     .016

01/01/2023 12:02am              1012                     .033

.

.

.

01/04/2023 12:00am              1100                      72

01/04/2023 12:01am              1108                    72.016

.

.

.

It can be assumed that the lines with dots represent on-going work for the timeframe. The issue is the Total Time. The work was completed for the day on 01/01/2023, but they returned back to work on 01/04/2023. I have a column that is doing the DateDiff between a "Start Time" and "End Time" column, but I'm not exactly sure how I can subtract the difference between the real time worked vs the down time. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks!

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you clarify? How do we know when the work was completed? What is your desired result (e.g. please show a mocked up column with the desired values)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The desired column/goal is to gather the total time worked (Total Time Worked (Hrs) column). I'm looking to find large breaks in the Date-Time Stamp column. Example shown above has the start date of 01/01/2023 at 12am, but there was a time break/gap between 01/01/2023 and 01/04/2023. The work stopped on the 1st and then started again on the 4th. I thought of having a column flag that would check the logic between times (ex: if Column X was greater than 5 hours, flag as "end of work"), but not sure how to incorporate that because we still need the times from those rows.

Comment: As far as knowing when the work is completed, we only know that each row entered is a reflection of every minute. If the date changes by more than 3-4 days (01/01 to 01/04) or there is a large gap between entry times, we can assume that they left the job and came back at the later date to resume. My DateDiff code in Spotfire gives the total time between dates, but if the workers didn't work any days between the 1st and the 4th, that's an inaccurate reflection of actual time worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from my understanding, the column you want to calculate would give you the running time actually worked.
You then can add it up as a KPI or cross table or an extra calculated column if you wish.

If there are no extra grouping variables in your actual data, and assuming you calculate the time in some defined unit (here I am using minutes but I suspect it is not)
then you could do this:

1 - create a standard date difference column, with respect to the *previous* time.
I am assuming the data is already in the right order (if not, you might have to introduce an intermediate row_id variable).
Say this column will be called [Time Gap]:

```
SN(DateDiff('minute',Max([Date-Time Stamp]) over (previous([Date-Time Stamp])),[Date-Time Stamp]),0.0)
```

SN(..,0.0) handles the first row, where there is no previous timestamp.

2 - calculate the total time worked [Time Worked] by substituting [Time Gap] with 0.0 every time it exceeds a certain value (here using 1000 as an example)

```
case  when [Time Gap]<1000 then [Time Gap] else 0.0 end
```

3 - to calculate (for instance) the cumulative time worked as a column:

```
Sum([Time Worked]) OVER (AllPrevious([Date-Time Stamp]))
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! I appreciate the help and the time that went into this solution.